# Is planting on the graves forbidden?

Tags: sharia, hadith, sunni, sunnah, grave

I was told from Salafi guy that planting on the grave is forbidden as Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) did it only for himself and none of the Sahaba did it.

The Hanafis, Shafi`is, and Hanbalis have all declared it to be recommended to place green stalks and the likes on the graves.

If Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) did it, I wonder why the Sahaba didn't follow it (if that is true)? Can it be an innovation?

Comment: innovation is changing a law of Islam. if Sahaba did not an action, it is not enough proof for that action being innovation. first existence of that law in Islam should be proved.

Comment: they lived in desert and maybe they could not plant. heading of post and main part are about different things. if you just lie a green stalk on ground, that is not planting, it will not grow in almost 100% of cases on earth nowadays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true that the Prophet ﷺ did this, but this was specific for the Prophet ﷺ alone.

> مَرَّ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم بِحَائِطٍ مِنْ حِيطَانِ
> الْمَدِينَةِ أَوْ مَكَّةَ، فَسَمِعَ صَوْتَ إِنْسَانَيْنِ يُعَذَّبَانِ
> فِي قُبُورِهِمَا، فَقَالَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏
> يُعَذَّبَانِ، وَمَا يُعَذَّبَانِ فِي كَبِيرٍ ‏"‏، ثُمَّ قَالَ ‏"‏
> بَلَى، كَانَ أَحَدُهُمَا لاَ يَسْتَتِرُ مِنْ بَوْلِهِ، وَكَانَ الآخَرُ
> يَمْشِي بِالنَّمِيمَةِ ‏"‏‏.‏ ثُمَّ دَعَا بِجَرِيدَةٍ فَكَسَرَهَا
> كِسْرَتَيْنِ، فَوَضَعَ عَلَى كُلِّ قَبْرٍ مِنْهُمَا كِسْرَةً‏.‏
> فَقِيلَ لَهُ يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ لِمَ فَعَلْتَ هَذَا قَالَ ‏"‏
> لَعَلَّهُ أَنْ يُخَفَّفَ عَنْهُمَا مَا لَمْ تَيْبَسَا أَوْ إِلَى أَنْ
> يَيْبَسَا ‏"
>
> Once the Prophet, while passing through one of the graveyards of
> Medina or Mecca heard the voices of two persons who were being
> tortured in their graves. The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "These two persons are
> being tortured not for a major sin (to avoid)." The Prophet (ﷺ) then
> added, "Yes! (they are being tortured for a major sin). Indeed, one of
> them never saved himself from being soiled with his urine while the
> other used to go about with calumnies (to make enmity between
> friends). The Prophet (ﷺ) then asked for a green leaf of a date-palm
> tree, broke it into two pieces and put one on each grave. On being
> asked why he had done so, he replied, "I hope that their torture might
> be lessened, till these get dried."

[صحيح بخاري (Bukari)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/4/82)

And it is important to note that this is a point of difference among scholars, so you have some saying that it is recommended and some that is not.  The most correct is that this was specific to the Prophet ﷺ only, and that he ﷺ did it as intercession from him.

> إِنِّي مَرَرْتُ بِقَبْرَيْنِ يُعَذَّبَانِ فَأَحْبَبْتُ بِشَفَاعَتِي
> أَنْ يُرَفَّهَ عَنْهُمَا مَا دَامَ الْغُصْنَانِ رَطْبَيْنِ
>
> I passed by two graves the occupants of which had been undergoing
> torment. I liked to make intercession for them so that they might be
> relieved of this torment as long as these twigs remain fresh

[صحيح مسلم (Muslim)](http://sunnah.com/muslim/55/94)

[This (Arabic)](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/24505) is available for more information.

It is not necessarily an innovation (at least I wouldn't call it such), but it was done from the Prophet ﷺ as benefit for the two in the grave, but this as I said was specific to the Prophet himself ﷺ.  So we/those who are alive are highly recommended to do that which would benefit the dead as is in the Shariah, like Sadaqah and Dua'.

Comment: This is a great answer but it must be noted by those seeking answer to the question that the prophet did not PLANT trees on the grave. Just kept green leaves on them